# Highlighting and adding text to and hours table

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

So I have a table of open hour (which are pulled in dynamically from expression engine). I have a script that adds a class to the `<tr>` to highlight the line as being open. However I can't figure out two things. I'm trying to add the class, but only at certain hours, on certain days, such as 8:30 - 5pm on weekdays.

this is the table of hours (the actual hours are being generated by EE)

```
<table class="table-plain branch-hours">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="Monday">
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>8:30am - 5pm</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Tuesday">
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>8:30am - 5pm</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Wednesday">
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>8:30am - 5pm</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Thursday">
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>8:30am - 5pm</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Friday">
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>8:30am - 5pm</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Saturday">
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td>Closed</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr><tr class="Sunday">
        <td>Sunday</td>
        <td>Closed</td>

        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var date = new Date().getDay() -1;
document.getElementsByTagName('TR')[date].className += " open-now";
</script>
```

Comment: "*First, I need to actually the js to the actual hours open*" - what does that mean?

Comment: Shouldn't that be document.getElementsByTagName('TR')[date].className += "     open-now"; ?

Comment: CSS will add the "open now" to the third table cell: TR.open-now TD:last-of-type::after {content: "Open Now!";}

Comment: @DavidThomas meaning I need some way of making sure that the class is only applied during the actual hour they're open.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i am wrong, but you want to highlight the day of the week we currently are

Since you are using pure javascript, i created a array with days of the week, so i can get the `TR` we need, we are doing the search by class so we get an array, in the example i assume that we only have ONE monday, tuesday, etc...

```
var dayofWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thurday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var day = new Date().getDay();
var now = new Date();

var trs = document.getElementsByClassName(dayofWeek[day]);
var tdHour = trs[0].getElementsByTagName('TD')[1];
var hours = tdHour.innerHTML.split(' - ')
var from = hours[0].replace('am','').replace('pm','').split(':');
var to = hours[1].replace('am','').replace('pm','').split(':');

if(hours[0].indexOf('pm') > -1)
    from[0] = parseInt(from[0]) +12;

if(hours[1].indexOf('pm') > -1)
    to[0] = parseInt(to[0]) +12;

var dFrom = new Date();

dFrom.setHours(from[0]);

if(from.length > 1)
    dFrom.setMinutes(from[1]);

var dTo = new Date();

dTo.setHours(to[0]);

if(to.length > 1)
    dTo.setMinutes(to[1]);

if( now >= dFrom && now <= dTo)
    trs[0].className = 'open-now';
```

[Here is a link for the working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr9h47ha/2/)

But this would be MUCH, MUCH simpler if you would just add the Class when the table is being formed.